# How create a remote websoket sever python on Raspi

Tags: python, web, websocket, server

I've got Raspberry Pi and I want to create a websocket server in python to which I could access remotely from a website.

I've got a few ideas to how I can make it, with the python libraries Tornado or WebSocket. In this way I've successfully created a python websocket server to which I access from a website... but locally.

So now, how can I make this server distant? I've seen that I need a ws:// or wss:// address, but I don't how to implement it in my first version's server.

server.py :

```
import os.path
import tornado.httpserver
import tornado.websocket
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

#Tornado Folder Paths
settings = dict(
   template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
   static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "static")
   )

# Server port
PORT = 70

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
     print ("[HTTP](MainHandler) User Connected.")
     self.render("index.html")

    
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
  def open(self):
    print ('[WS] Connection was opened.')
 
  def on_message(self, message):
    print ('[WS] Incoming message: ' + message)  

  def on_close(self):
    print ('[WS] Connection was closed.')


application = tornado.web.Application([
  (r'/', MainHandler),
  (r'/ws', WSHandler),
  ], **settings)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
        http_server.listen(PORT)


        main_loop = tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance()

        print ("Tornado Server started")
        main_loop.start()

    except:
        print ("Exception triggered - Tornado Server stopped.")
```

Comment: You need to find out the IP address of your Raspi using e.g. `hostname -I` (that's a capital `i`). Then run the server on you Raspi using `python server.py` (for a start, there are other options). Then, using that IP address and port `70` (BTW 80 would be the typical port for HTTP) you should be able to connect to your server from another PC. Assuming both of your devices are in the same local network and there is no firewall rule blocking incoming connections on that port on the raspberry pi. You can now on your PC open a browser and enter `http://<ip-of-raspi>:70` and see your website.

Comment: Using [nmap](https://nmap.org/) you may check if the port is open on your raspberry pi. Use `nmap -p <your-port> <ip-of-raspi>` and wait for the result. E.g. assuming your port is `70` and the IP of the Raspi in your LAN is `192.168.178.21` use `nmap -p 70 192.168.178.21` to check if the port is open.

Comment: I all ready know how run it on my local network but now I want to run it on the internet and for that I now that I need to create a ws:// address...

Comment: Oh ok, so want you want is to by a domain e.g. `my-domain.com`. Please check out [this guide](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/beginners-guide-what-is-a-domain-name-and-how-do-domains-work/) to get started. As you do want to host your server on your Raspberry Pi at home you probably need to use [DynDNS](https://www.n-able.com/blog/dynamic-dns-overview#:~:text=With%20a%20dynamic%20DNS%20program,to%20the%20right%20host%20server.). Also make sure to read on some measures to secure your Raspi as it will be accessable from the internet. [Fail2Ban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail2ban)

Comment: Yes thank, I already know that and how create and link a domain to raspi. But here I know that I need to create a domain not http but ws and I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: You are mixing things here. DNS connects a domain to an IP address which you define, nothing else. `HTTP` and `WS` are just different protocols which have nothing to do with the domain. So connection to `http://my-domain.com` will connect to the same IP address as `ws://my-domain.com` just the protocol used differs. You can compare that to languages. So you are still speaking to the same person but once in `English` and another time in `Spanish`. As long as the person can speak both it will work. Meaning, as long as your server knows how to speak HTTP and WS both will work.

Comment: As you have a WS (= WebSocket) server (I don't know the framework, so I am not sure you do) you should be able to communicate with it. You only need a WS client to do that.